# HTML5 Drag and Drop : display droppable elements in separate div (Java Script and Knockout JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, knockout.js

I am beginner in Knockout and java script. I have a problem in my project. I am using HTML5 Drag and Drop API using Knockout javascript. Now I need to show all drop items in separate div. I have some code which is display the name of droppable Items. But I want display file not file name. Below is my sample demo.

I am okay with either knockout or pure java script.
[image]

[**VIEW FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/vhdhfbx3/)

```js
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    this.dropZones = ko.observableArray([{
        'elements' : ko.observableArray([])  // just to see that the output is correct
    }]);

    this.dragover = function(e){
        console.log('dragOver');
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    this.drop = function(e, data){
        console.log('drop');
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            data.elements.push(f.name);
        }
        $('.drop_zone').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
    }

    this.dragenter = function(e, index){
        console.log('dragEnter');
        $('.drop_zone').eq(index).css('background-color', '#00ff00');
    }

    this.dragleave = function(e, index){
        console.log('end');
        $('.drop_zone').eq(index).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
.drop_zone {
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 20pt bold'Vollkorn';
    color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: dropZones">
    <div class="drop_zone" data-bind="event:{
                dragover:   function(data, e){ $root.dragover(e);},
                drop:       function(data, e){ $root.drop(e, $data);},
                dragenter:  function(data, e){ $root.dragenter(e, $index());},
                dragleave:  function(data, e){ $root.dragleave(e, $index());}
            }">Drop files here</div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: elements" style="height: 100px">
        <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: when you say you want to display the file and not the file name, do you mean you want the full path to be displayed too? because if so, that information is not available on the File object (security reasons)

Comment: @dperry , I attached my image what I need , Please have a look and help me to resolve. and you can use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/vhdhfbx3/9/) this link also

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to get an image from a file and append it to a `.preview` element:

```
function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function(_file) {
        image.src    = _file.target.result;            
        image.onload = function() {
          $(".preview").append('<img src="' + this.src + '"/>' + '<p>' + this.name +'</p>');
        };     
    };

}
```

[And a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/vhdhfbx3/9/). HTH.

Comment: this is useful for me. I have problem in this. When i drop image it will useful. I need to do drop some Excel files and some text files also. In that case how can I proceed. Is there any thing excel to image conversation.

Comment: Do you need to read/write the file *contents* or just indicate the file type by using an icon?

Comment: sorry for this, initially i need to show icon. once I will click on that icon a popup will come in that I need to show that file(either image or text file). same like g mail.